# Loudness Normalisation LUFS in C# with NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, buffer, wav, naudio

I am looking for informations on how to do a loudness normalisation (LUFS EBU128) with NAudio.

I need to read .wav files (not play them) who could be mono/stereo/multichannel and get their loudness value, I don't actually need to modify the files just get the value. I have no problem reading the files adapting one of the examples from NAudio :

```
    private static void ReadWavFile(FileInfo inputFile)
    {
        using (var inAudio = new WaveFileReader(inputFile.FullName))
        {
            //Calculate required byte[] buffer.
            var buffer = new byte[10 * inAudio.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond];//Assume average will be constant for WAV format.

            int index = 0;
            do
            {
                int bytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = inAudio.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - bytesRead);
               
                } while (bytesRead > 0 && bytesRead < buffer.Length);

                index++;
            } while (inAudio.Position < inAudio.Length);
        }
    }
```

But I cannot find how to do a the loudness normalization part within NAudio. Is it possible ?

If it's not possible I also found other tools but they ask for a double[][] buffer while NAudio provides a byte[] or float[] one. Would it be possible to convert it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The difference, I would think, is that NAudio provides an interleaved array. If this is a stereo buffer then the first sample would be for the left channel, and the next sample would be for the right channel. So to do this conversion you would simply just make a new jagged array where each array is half the length of the original array and move each sample to the correct jagged array.

```
var jaggedArray = new double[numberOfChannels][];

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; ++i)
{
  jaggedArray[i] = new double[source.Length / numberOfChannels];
}

for(int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += numberOfChannels)
{
 for(int j = 0; j < numberOfChannels; ++j)
 {
    jaggedArray[j][i / numberOfChannels] =  source[i + j];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you even though it's a bit late.